# Vulkan, Can I transition the depth stencil before the previous render pass has finished all writes?

Tags: vulkan

I am following the Vulkan tutorial. When he adds a depth attachment to the rendering he changes the subpass dependency to:

```
.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
.dstSubpass = 0;
.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT; 
.srcAccessMask = 0; // 0 here implies that the image must already be available, as after waiting for the semaphore, or that we don't care about flushing the resource. I think.
.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
```

The tutorial claims that: The [depth stencil] reading happens in the VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT stage and the writing in the VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT.

My question is: What happens to the writes in the late frag test, from the earlier subpass, which can here happen after the depth attachment layout transition? Aren't we transitioning/reading the depth attachment before the previous pass is done writing to it.

Comment: I feel Overvoorde should comment on what Overvoorde's code does. Why not ask him, and give him the opportunity to improve his materials?

Comment: Given the `0` access mask, the likelihood is the previous use is a Semaphore wait, and the stages are only chaining stages, but I am not an Overvoordeologist...

Comment: I depersonalized it and call it "the" Vulkan tutorial. I have read some similar questions but I don't understand the answers. I feel the answers are avoiding the question. So I put srcStage = late_frag_test and moved on. I am just curious if there is something smart happening here that makes it safe to clear the depth stencil before the previous pass have left the late frag test. I read your answers here and there and I usually think they hold a lot of value and credibility. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Well, what is the question we are avoiding? It is probably correct, because the previous use is a semaphore and therefore there is no previous pass. Alternatively the previous pass could be read-only. Otherwise, yea the code is wrong and the original author should comment on it or be made aware of the problem. You have not really included more than the barrier cut out of context. FYI the problem was not with the attribution, rather than a tutorial purpose is to make things clear. It is not something we should be substituting in here and commenting on someone elses code than the asker's.

Comment: I admit the question is lacking. I wanted to write a short question and was hoping that since this tutorial is so obliquitous  that the context would be understood. I overestimated the value of quoting a public code base.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vulkan Synchronization: Avoiding write after write hazard, why this is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76264323/vulkan-synchronization-avoiding-write-after-write-hazard-why-this-is-correct)

Comment: Thank you for remembering this question. I settled on something and moved on, graphics good enough for prototyping. I don't have this fresh in my mind anymore and will delay answering until time has come to tidy up the graphics.

Comment: It was asked again yesterday, and I found this Q while looking for the other answer. Apparently this is commonly asked. I poked the tutorial author for you guys at https://github.com/Overv/VulkanTutorial/issues/308. And perhaps I could also ask validation layers to implement this as error...