# VkSubpassDependency with depthAttachment

Tags: vulkan

I'm learning from the tutorial https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Depth_buffering and want to understand this code:

```
dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
```

dstStageMask determines that the early depth test will not occur until the image is cleared. But why does srcStageMask contain VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT? Is this the stage where the cleanup happens? Also, doesn't srcSubpass denote commands outside of renderPass, if so, why does the cleanup command occur before renderPass?

Comment: I feel a tutorial maker should perhaps be explaining their code, not general community.

Comment: krOoze, you're right, but I'm not sure he's still answering (the tutorial is not new, anyway)

Comment: krOoze, It seems to me that this synchronization does not make sense at all, because clearing when loading attachment occurs before the transition layout subpass, or am I wrong?

Comment: Apparently already asked: https://github.com/Overv/VulkanTutorial/issues/308. By a quick inspection, it looks like a bug to me, and should be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`+`VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT`, referencing Store Operation (`VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE`) of the previous Render Pass execution.

Comment: krOoze. I think I understand now. We are synchronizing the recording in this attachment of the previous frame with the current one, because it is one, and the frames in flight are two, and the recording in it is just in VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT. Is this correct?

Comment: That was my impression of the author's intent, then again I was only scrolling through the code for 20 seconds...

Comment: I knew it sounded familiar. Here me answering this: [Vulkan Synchronization: Avoiding write after write hazard, why this is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76264323/vulkan-synchronization-avoiding-write-after-write-hazard-why-this-is-correct)

Comment: krOoze, I read the specification and it says: "loadOp is a VkAttachmentLoadOp value specifying how the contents of color and depth components of the attachment are treated at the beginning of the subpass where it is first used". That is, after the transition of the layout. The author's idea was to synchronize clearOp loadOp with the layout transition. The meaning is not clear.

Comment: That would in of itself be unnecessary, since it is covered by the implicit dependency, and also messing with `src*` parameters would do nothing towards that goal. Indeed I think there was a failed attempt to reuse the depth buffer between frames. Somewhat interesting if validation layers (with sync validation enabled) do not complain about this...

Comment: krOoze, thank you, you helped me understand this synchronization!